JsonResponse is not outputing the data in the correct structure
I have the following view function which takes the daily stock prices, and convert them to weekly prices. When I return JsonResponse it does not output the values in the correct form.
def weeklyPrices(request, ticker):
    prices = DailyCandles.objects.filter(symbol=ticker.upper()).all().values()
    weekly = pd.DataFrame(list(prices))
    logic = {'open'  : 'first',
            'high'  : 'max',
            'low'   : 'min',
            'close' : 'last',
            'volume': 'sum'}
    weekly['date'] = pd.to_datetime(weekly['date'])
    weekly.set_index('date', inplace=True)
    weekly.sort_index()
    weekly = weekly.resample('W').apply(logic)
    weekly.index = weekly.index - pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset('6D')
    weekly.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    return JsonResponse(weekly.to_dict(), safe=False)

The output:
    
open    
0   "134.19"
1   "137.0"
2   "136.63"
high    
0   "137.73"
1   "138.4"
2   "137.74"

The expected output is where all the values (open, high, low, close) in row 0 are places together, rather then being placed separately.
